# Angular, confuse with console result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am very new to the angular. I'm confused with the console output of a angular app. First, see what I have did so far!

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
                {{getCourse()}}
            `,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    code = ['C++', "Python", "JAVA", 'ReactJS', "Angular"];
    getCourse()
    {
        for(let i = 0 ; i < (this.code).length ; i++)
        {
            console.log(this.code[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the **AppComponent** has one array **code** and one method **getCourse()**. I used inline template and data bind with **getCourse()** and this method iterate over the array and print on console. Here, is my console output. 
[image] 
See, here the same output repeated 4 times, not 1 time. 
Why? I wrote the logic to iterate the loop for one time.

Comment: Why do you call `getSource()` in the template? You would typically call it once (maybe in `constructor()` or `ngOnInit()`), assign to a model, and render the model in the template. A function call like this triggers a lot of change detection and should be avoided.

Comment: Actually I tried to check whether this type function call works or not and now I understand this outcome is happen because of change detection. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - because of change detection. Your template rerenders (and do your `getCourse()` method) after any event on component or it descendants happened.

If you want to control changedetection maualy you have to set

```
@Component({
    ....
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    ...
})
```

Add `ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor, and trigger `this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();` when you need rerender.

Also there some rules when change detection triggered byitself in case of OnPush strategy, for example on change Input value.

see for more info about change detection

https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular/